# Catalan constant preliminaries

Tags: calculus, integration, catalans-constant

I recently ran across this representation of :

$$ \Bigg[ \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}=\frac{1}{x^{2}(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}})=\frac{1}{x^{2}}(1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x^{4}}-\frac{1}{x^{6}}+\frac{1}{x^{8}}...)}\Bigg]$$

I believe the nonending term in the denominator comes from long division but I do not understand how this is derived. Any help is welcomed.

I also saw a different form of the $\arctan(x)$ integral and I don't understand where it comes from. The $\arctan(x)$ integral:

$$\int_0^x \frac{dy}{(1+y^{2})}$$ can be written as:
 $$ \arctan(x)= \int_0^x (1-y^{2}+y^{4}-y^{6}+y^{8}-...)dy$$ Evidently the integrand as written comes from a long division process derived from the original integrand but I don't see how. Again, any help would be welcomed.

Comment: I don't understand the first, displayed, equation.  (1) What are the red M symbols?  And (2), what does that second = sign in the denominator of the right-hand side mean?  How can one divide by an equation?

Comment: the red symbols came from latex, which I am new to, so my mistake, the whole expression I took from a book, I have since, with the help of the responses, resolved my issue. it is just a matter of converting to a geometric series and then plugging the series into an integral.

Answer (score 1):

Take $y=\tan u $so $$dy=(1+\tan ^2 u) du $$ put into $\int \frac{dy}{(1+y^{2})}$ an you will have 
$$\int \frac{dy}{(1+y^{2})}=\int \frac{(1+\tan ^2 u) du}{1+\tan ^2 u }$$simplify 
$$\int \frac{(1+\tan ^2 u) du}{1+\tan ^2 u }=\int 1du =u$$ now $$y=\tan u \to u=\arctan y\\\int_0^x\frac{dy}{(1+y^{2})}=\arctan y|^x_0=\arctan x $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1-z+z^2-z^3+z^4-z^5+\cdots$ is a geometric series with the common ratio of $-z$. Also, $1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^n = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$. Consequently, if $|z|<1$ then  $$1-z+z^2-z^3+z^4-z^5+\cdots = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-(-z)^n}{1+z}= \frac{1}{1+z}.$$ In your examples, $z = 1/x^2$ or $y^2$.

Comment: thanks, you just answered the question I posed above, I should have read further down, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is malformed.

$$\Bigg[ \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}
=\frac{1}{x^{2}(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}})
=\frac{1}{x^{2}}(1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x^{4}}-\frac{1}{x^{6}}+\frac{1}{x^{8}}...)}\Bigg]
$$
should be
$$ \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}
=\frac{1}{x^{2}(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}})}
=\frac{1}{x^{2}}(1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x^{4}}-\frac{1}{x^{6}}+\frac{1}{x^{8}}...)
$$

Comment: And this should be a comment on the question, no? (Or even better, an edit)

Comment: No. It tells why the first question could not be solved as stated and shows how to solve it.

Comment: How exactly does it show how to solve anything?

Comment: thanks Marty, now the whole thing works, I think there was a misprint in what I was looking at. Where does that series come from though, is it a power series for 1+x^2?